# How can i convert Integer to Signed Word in Python (for use with PySerial)?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm having some problems making Python talk to a hardware display using pyserial.
Some of the display's functions require a signed word to be sent as arguments after commands (ie. X or Y on display screen).

I've been getting by with chr() previously, but that only works with numbers < 255.

I've tried the following for conversion but it's giving some weird results, placing things way off the set position:

```
def ByteIt(self,data):
    datastring = str()
    for each in tuple(str(data)):
        datastring = datastring + chr(int(each))
    return datastring
```

I may be way off myself here :)

Example of how i would use it:

```
x = 100
y = 350
serial.Write('\x01' + ByteIt(x) + ByteIt(y)) # command , xpos , ypos
```

The thing is, when i do this, the stuff is not placed at x100,y350, most times the display will crash :(

Any tips on how this can be done properly?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just write `serial.Write('\x01' + str(x)+str(y))` or something to that effect?

Comment: Not sure why, but i think when i did that the display would print it instead of executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about the `struct` module.

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Replace all of the "chr" and stuff with proper `struct.pack()` calls.

Specifically

```
bytes = struct.pack( 'h', some_data )
```

Should give you a "signed word".

Comment: Did you read the doc?  `pack('>HH', freq, millisecs )` is what you should have done.

Comment: pack('>H',freq) + pack('>H',millsecs)
...did the job in a similar function!

Thanks! :)

Comment: great tips Lott! thanks again! I was a little quick reading it i must admit :)

Comment: @Kanonskall: `pack('>H',freq) + pack('>H',millsecs)` may appear to work, but it's wrong in a serious way.  The BigEndian LittleEndian part is wrong when you do this concatenation business.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to revise again the documentation about "pack" and "unpack". Selecting the appropriate upper-case or lower-case allows you to specify the Endianness. So, based on the example above which didn't work perfectly on your device, I presume you need:

```
x = 100
y = 350
serial.Write('\x01' + 
             struct.pack('>hh', x) + 
             struct.pack('>hh', y)) # command , xpos , ypos
```